# Where are Eclipse preferences stored?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, config

Can you please break down where eclipse stores its preferences?
There are some in the workspace directory. Perhaps there are other stored in the installation directory? Where else?
Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The majority of configuration is saved in the various folders in the workspace `.metadata` folder. This includes most preferences.

A few values, such as the list of workspaces, are stored in the `configuration` directory in the Eclipse install (these are 'configuration scope' preferences).

Preferences using the 'instance scope' of the standard Eclipse preferences system are in the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` folder in `xxx.prefs` files (which are Java Properties files).

It is also possible to have per-project 'project scope' preferences. These are stored in a `.settings` folder in the project.

Comment: Thanks! Do you happen know if there is a way to get a list of all preferences and/or where they are stored? (for a script I'm writing..)

Comment: There is no definitive list because each plugin has its own preferences and there are lots of plugins. Preferences using the standard Eclipse preferences system are in the `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` folder in `xxx.prefs` files (which are Java Properties files).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for your help :)

Comment: @greg-449 What will be stored in **.eclipse** folder?

Comment: @ChandrayyaGK I think that is used if the install directory is read only. I don't have a .eclipse directory on my Mac.

Comment: @greg-449 Hopefully, the question is now passable and worthy of delicious upvotes..?  :)

Comment: @Inversus - just a note, Preferences can be exported: File -> Export,,, -> General -> Preferences